# Assigning the value of String variable to another String variable

Tags: java, android, string

I have a check box and according to its status value of the code variable should change. Because I'm using it to next activity.

I have code as shown below,

```
String code;
String itemCode;
String MayoItemCode;

mayoBaseCB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mayoBaseCB.isChecked()) {
                    code = (MayoItemCode);

                } else {
                    code.equals(itemCode);
                }
            }

        });
```

`itemcode` and `MayotItemCode` has values and I want to assign it to the variable code according to the status of the checkbox.

I have tried these 2 ways (equaling) but it didn't work for me. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be assigning in your `else` block?

Comment: what happens in your next activity does it get the String var as null ?

Comment: I got it as null, but its working now, thanks alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are invoking `code.equals`, which checks for `String` content equality and returns `boolean` (you are not using the outcome of the invocation).

Not sure I understand the question but you might want to assign instead, with the `=` idiom.

I.e.

```
} else {
    code = itemCode;
}
```

**Edit**

On second thought, since you are using an anonimized idiom, you need your fields outside your anonymous `View.OnClickListener` to be `final`.

Yet again, assignment would not compile as illustrated in your example, with `final` fields.

What you may want to use is a mutable `CharSequence` (i.e. a `StringBuilder`), and manipulate it through method invocation.

Sounds fishy though, but there's not enough information (and scope) to help you further.

Comment: When I changed the else block it worked, thanks alot for the explanation a s well

Answer (score 0):

You Should replace you **if** block with:

```
if (mayoBaseCB.isChecked()) {
                code = MayoItemCode;

            } else {
                code = itemCode;
            }
```

**.equals()** method just used for comparision not for assigning value